# Uploading an HTML page to Sharepoint Library using Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, sharepoint

I receive maintenance reports for certain devices by being emailed a link. I click the link and get an html page in my browser. This appears to be a REST request to me.

What I want to do is create a Chrome browser action that when clicked will upload that html file to a *Sharepoint Document library*. I'm not sure where to get started with this. I was attempting to create an `XMLHttprequest` to get the file and then I was going to look at using the sharepoint rest API to upload it, but I am getting no where.  I am hoping to get some recommendations on which way to go.